# Modifying mergesort program to support searching subarrays

Tags: java, mergesort

I have been stuck for about a week now trying to modify a mergesort program to support searching subarrays. The user would give an unsorted list of words as command-line arguments along with the starting and ending index of the subarray that should be sorted. The program should print out a list where the strings between the given indexes are sorted alphabetically.

**Two sample test cases could be:-**

**Case 1:-**

```
command:- java MergeSort 2 4 toy apply sand bay cat dog fish

Expected Output:- toy apply bay cat sand dog fish
```

**Case 2:-**

```
command:- java MergeSort 0 3 was had him and you his the but

Expected Output:- and had him was you his the but
```

The code that I am trying to modify is below:

```
public class MergeSort {
    public static void sort(Comparable[] a)
    {
        Comparable [] aux = new Comparable[a.length];
        sort(a, aux, 0, a.length);
    }
    
    private static void sort(Comparable[] a, Comparable[] aux, int lo, int hi)
    { 
    if (hi - lo <= 1) return;
    int mid = lo + (hi-lo)/2;
    sort(a, aux, lo, mid);
    sort(a, aux, mid, hi);
    int i = lo, j = mid;
    for (int k = lo; k < hi; k++)
        if (i == mid) aux[k] = a[j++];
        else if (j == hi) aux[k] = a[i++];
        else if (a[j].compareTo(a[i]) < 0) aux[k] = a[j++];
        else                               aux[k] = a[i++];
        
    for (int k = lo; k < hi; k++)
        a[k] = aux[k];
    }
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        
        String[] a = StdIn.readAllStrings();
        sort(a);
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            StdOut.print(a[i] + " ");
        StdOut.println();
        
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am new to Java and have only been in the programming world for about 2 months now!

Comment: You want to sort only the specified subarray? `Arrays` , the utility class for arrays, has methods that can do that. Note that when specifying the start index and ending index, the start index is inclusive, while the end index is exclusive.

Comment: By the way, it would help to have input _and_ expected output with your question.

Comment: James, the input and expected output given the input is what I put in the post as the sample runs. And right now, my program is Merging a user inputted text file and sorting all of the words in the text file. I am trying to figure out how to get my program to take a user inputting the first two args as a start index and end index, and for the user after that to be able to input as many words as they want and it will sort between the specified indexes but leave the rest of the words unsorted.

Comment: I read the sample runs as input, in which the arrays had duplicated elements.

Comment: James, my apologies, I am still getting used to stack overflow. I just fixed it.

Comment: So, to be clear, you're looking to reimplement [`java.util.Arrays.sort(T[], int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object%5B%5D,int,int)), yes?  And when you say "*searching* subarrays", you mean *sorting* subarrays?

Comment: Look carefully at the code you posted.  Does not the `sort(Comparable[], Comparable[], int, int)` method do exactly what you want, except for having an extra input? Have a look at the `sort(Comparable[])` method and how it invokes the other.  Do you get any ideas?  We really can't hint this very much without working the whole problem for you.